# sum() function in cakephp query

Tags: cakephp

I am using this query, but it is not returning `ctotal`. Please help.

```
$total = $this->RequestedItem->find('all',
    [
        'sum(cost * quantity) AS ctotal', 
        'conditions' => [
            'RequestedItem.purchase_request_id' => $_GET['po_id']
         ]
     ]
);
```

Comment: You probably want to avoid putting $_GET['po_id'] into a query directly, even if CakePHP is scrubbing the user input for you.

Comment: @Dave if CakePHP already handles injection, what is the harm?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not be using PHP superglobals directly in CakePHP. You should instead use `Model.field` naming so that you do not get ambiguous field errors.

Virtual fields is the way to go but that is not your problem, you need to read the book some more.

```
$total = $this->RequestedItem->find('all', array(array('fields' => array('sum(Model.cost * Model.quantity)   AS ctotal'), 'conditions'=>array('RequestedItem.purchase_request_id'=>$this->params['named']['po_id'])));
```

should work fine, with the virtualFields it would be

```
var $virtualFields = array('total' => 'SUM(Model.cost * Model.quantity)');
$total = $this->RequestedItem->find('all', array(array('fields' => array('total'), 'conditions'=>array('RequestedItem.purchase_request_id'=>$this->params['named']['po_id'])));
```

Fields go in the 'fields' key, just like conditions go in the 'conditions' key. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find

Answer (score 8):

This works too, worked fine for me

```
    $sum = $this->Modelname->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'Modelname.fieldname' => $conditions),
    'fields' => array('sum(Modelname.fieldname) as total_sum'
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily set the virtualFields prior to doing a find.

```
$this->MaterialScan->virtualFields = array(
    'total_qty' => 'COUNT(MaterialScan.id)',
    'total_lbs' => 'SUM(MaterialScan.weight)'
);
$materialScans = $this->MaterialScan->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'MaterialScan.id' => $scans
    ),
    'group' => array('MaterialScan.part_number')
));
```

This avoids having the [0] elements in the returned array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use virtualFields:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'the_sum' => 'SUM(Model.cost * Model.quantity)'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a `sum()` function among other commonly used SQL functions. See further information in the [documentation: "Using SQL Functions"](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions).

I didn't use a `find('all')` and made my solution via [Salines' answer to "how to get sum of column in datatable using cakephp"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296898/). This worked for me. I also replaced your use of PHP superglobals with `$this->params['named']['po_id']]`. FYI, I am using CakePHP3.

```
$total = $this->RequestedItem->find();
$total->select([
       'RequestedItem.purchase_request_id',
       'ctotal' => $total->func()->sum('cost * quantity')
   ])
   ->where(['RequestedItem.purchase_request_id' => $this->params['named']['po_id']]);
```