# How to get the sum of all the elements in an column in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Amount
100
2000
3000
400

I have a column in my database how can i do the sum in cakephp.
and print this value.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Use a virtual field.

Comment: <?php
   $sum = $this->records->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'records.Amount' => $conditions),
    'fields' => array('sum(records.Amount) as total_sum'
            )
        )
    );
   pr($sum);

   i have tried like this @arilia

Comment: don't put your attempts  in a comment: edit you question. Also include your cake version and tag the question with the right tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $sum = $this->records->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array( 'records.Amount' => $conditions), 'fields' => array('sum(records.Amount) as total_sum' ) ) );
 pr($sum);
```

Because i have checked my end given query like as

```
$sum = $this->Price->find('all', array('fields' => array('sum(Price.flag_fall) as total_sum' ) ) );
        pr($sum);
```

it give output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sum] => 305.600
                )

        )

)
```

I think this query is correct please check your $condition variable.
and for more information use below mention link.
[sum() function in cakephp query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971148/sum-function-in-cakephp-query)

I hope this will be more helpful

Thanks & Regards,
Krishan