# how to get sum of column in datatable using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have database column `(wallet)` in table `(users)`.

how can I get total amount of `(wallet)` where `role_id = 2` ?

what can I use `find('list')` and `SUM`?

> I'm using cakephp 2
>
> I got error, can you help me to fix it?

```
var $virtualFields = array('total_m' => 'SUM(User.wallet)');
$total_m = $this->RequestedItem->find('all', array(array('fields' => array('total_m'), 'conditions'=>array('RequestedItem.role_id'= 2 )));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please let us know which version of CakePHP you are using at least.

Comment: I am confused in using virtualFields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum() function in cakephp query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971148/sum-function-in-cakephp-query)

Comment: I get error, can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `find('list')`, you can use:

```
$query = $this->Users->find();
$query->select(['role_id', 'sum' => $query->func()->sum('wallet')])
   ->where(['role_id' => 2]);

return $query;
```

Start learning:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

Comment: sorry i forgot, i use cakephp 2